# Populating json in android ListView

Tags: android, json, listview

**My json output:**

```
[{"FirstName":"childname2"},{"FirstName":"childname4"}]
```

I have tried to populate my listview with json datas which i got by using post method,
By doing this i have got my total json `[{"FirstName":"childname2"},{"FirstName":"childname4"}]`  output in postexecute.And when i tried to pass this value in list by using for loop It didn't shows any error ,,,as well as not populating my list ,,
Suggestion ,,,,

**My java:**

```
private ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Toast.makeText(Certify_Child_Count.this,result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (result.equals("[]")) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(Certify_Child_Count.this,
                "Wrong Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    else 
    {
        Toast.makeText(Certify_Child_Count.this,result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        JSONArray arr=new JSONArray();
        JSONObject obj = null;
        //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Certify_Child_Count.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        //lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Certify_Child_Count.this,"going into for loop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {
            obj=arr.getJSONObject(i);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try { 
            list.add(obj.getString("FirstName"));
            Toast.makeText(Certify_Child_Count.this,obj.getString("FirstName"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        }

    }
    }
```

Comment: you should start parsing the information contained inside the json

Comment: What I didnt understand..how to do that

Comment: I mean, did you tried to look for it on google before asking ?

Comment: http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html. Many Samples are there you search

Comment: I mean here in my code there is no error ,, then why even not getting toast values,,,,,My for loop not works

Comment: In my for loop ,,, I have tried
 Toast.makeText(Certify_Child_Count.this,"going into for loop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   .,,,,It didnt works..

Answer (score 1):

You need use Adapter to populate your ListView.

You need create a Class to implement `ArraryAdapters<>`
For Example:

```
public class ListAdapters extends ArraryAdapters<string>
```

This class implement a `getView()` method. Here you need populate a listview.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_rows, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tectview = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.questionary_name);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


    String s = items[position];

    holder.tectview.setText(s);
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your adapter? You need an adapter for showing the data of your list. If it is a single text you can use basic adapter and notify it every time you complete your request and parse your data.

Comment: In my for loop ,,, I have tried Toast.makeText(Certify_Child_Count.this,"going into for loop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); .,,,,Even It didnt works..

Comment: Can you see  Toast.makeText(Certify_Child_Count.this,result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); toast?

Comment: If you can see the first toast and the result string is correct as you expect, then start with setting your json array object. Since you create an empty object, your array will be empty. Use JSONArray arr=new JSONArray(result); instead.

Comment: And I would recommend you move your toast out of the loop for a better semantic

Comment: When giving for(int i=arr.length();i<2;i++){} ,,Toast not works
But when givingfor(int i=2;i<2;i++),,,,Toast works,,,

Comment: Are you reading my comments? :) You are creating an empty array object (JSONArray arr=new JSONArray();) and using a loop traversing an empty array. Of course it will not work because your array's length is 0. You need to create the array from your result string (JSONArray arr=new JSONArray(result);).

Comment: Thank you,,,careless mistake

Comment: Then you remove your comments on your ArrayAdapter and list view adapter set. Add list.clear(); before you start parsing because you might need to request another post and since you didn't clear your list, you might have duplicated data. And don't forget to add adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); when you are done parsing. That means you notify your adapter that you can update your list.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
JSONArray arr=new JSONArray();
```

into

```
JSONArray arr=new JSONArray(result);
```

You are creating an empty `JSONArray` without adding the result.

Answer (score 0):

you are luckly, i just complete a demo almost the same with you. hope it can help you to solve the problem.

```
    package com.ecnu.vendingmachine;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import com.ecnu.vendingmachine.widgets.JSONParser;

public class VendingFragment extends ListFragment {

    private String Tag = "VendingFragment";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    private ListView listView;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray vendingmachine = null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> vendinglist;

    // url to get all products list
    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
    private String url_all_vendingmachine = main.getIP()
            + "vendingmachine/get_all_vendingmachine.php";

    // products JSONArray

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.vending_main, container, false);
    }

     @Override 
     public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        vendinglist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        //listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

        listView = getListView();
        new get_all_vendingmachine().execute();
    }   

    class get_all_vendingmachine extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            Log.i(Tag, "pDialog");
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            Log.i(Tag, url_all_vendingmachine);
            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_all_vendingmachine, "GET", params);

            // check log cat for response
            Log.i(Tag, json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // Ada record Data (SUCCESS = 1)
                    // Getting Array of vendingmachine
                    vendingmachine = json.getJSONArray("vendings");

                    // looping through All vendingmachine
                    for (int i = 0; i < vendingmachine.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = vendingmachine.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString("VMid");
                        String name = c.getString("Name");
                        String address = c.getString("Address");
                        Log.i(Tag, id);
                        Log.i(Tag, name);
                        Log.i(Tag, address);
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put("VMid", id);
                        map.put("Name", name);
                        map.put("Address", address);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        vendinglist.add(map);
                    }

                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // updating listview
                    // HashMap<String, String>中的key
                    String[] from = { "Name", "Address", "VMid" };
                    // list_item.xml中对应的控件ID
                    int[] to = { R.id.vending_name, R.id.vending_address,
                            R.id.vending_id };
                    Log.i(Tag, from[0]);
                    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                            vendinglist, R.layout.vending_list, from, to);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

the vending_main_xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/whiteColor" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_buy_title_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/headbar_title" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout_buy_title_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@drawable/reader_item_divider"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the vending_list.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/selectVmListCell_Height"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/selectVmListCell_Height"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_listview"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layout_Margin_10" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/imageTypeLayout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/smallImage_HW_45"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/vendingImage"
                style="@style/smallImageStyle"
                android:src="@drawable/buy_main_not_shop" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/distanceText"
                style="@style/smallTxtStyle"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/lightOrangeColor" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/vendingSave"
            android:layout_width="47.0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/vendingSaveImage"
                android:layout_width="27.0dip"
                android:layout_height="27.0dip"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_favor_btn" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_Margin_10"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/vendingSave"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageTypeLayout"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vending_name"
                style="@style/midDarkGrayTxtStyle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vending_address"
                style="@style/smallLightGrayTxtStyle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:maxLines="2" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/smallLightGrayTxtStyle"
                    android:text="Number：" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vending_id"
                    style="@style/smallLightGrayTxtStyle" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

hope it can help you to find how to put the listview into a fragment.
the element in my listview is complex, if you just want a single row, it's more simple than what i code.